# How to load the kendo grid data in button click not in page load

Tags: kendo-grid

I have kendo grid and chart in my application.And I have button also.At the time of page load all the data is loading in grid and chart.But i want to load the data in button click not in page load.In page load grid and chart will be empty.When we click on button data will be loaded in grid and chart.How to do this task.If any one know about this please help me.
My grid code is

```
 var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
autoBind:false,
dataSource: undefined,
pageable  : {
    pageSize : 10,
    refresh  : true,
    pageSizes: [10, 20]
},
columns   : [
    {
        field     : "OrderID",
        filterable: false
    },
    "Freight",
    {
        field : "OrderDate",
        title : "Order Date",
        width : 100,
        format: "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}"
    },
    {
        field: "ShipName",
        title: "Ship Name",
        width: 200
    },
    {
        field: "ShipCity",
        title: "Ship City"
    }
]

               }).data("kendoGrid");
```

My fiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/5bchz/103/

Comment: any update on if you found my answer useful or not?

Answer (score 13):

To stop auto loading the grid when the page load,

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
   autoBind: false,
   dataSource: dataSource
});
```

http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#configuration-autoBind

Then to set the grid to load you would need to put this in on the button onlick,

```
theGrid.dataSource.read()
```

Or in a jquery function so you can easily change which parameters you want to pass in with it.

Comment: Can this example be more details. How do i populate the datasource object with a MVC call?

Comment: @SomeRandomDeveloper that's not what the question was asking for which is why my answer is tailored for the least code required to implement the question requirement, also there should be plenty of examples on how to load kendo grid data, where as this question is about when to load data.